# Copying formula to proper column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have already wrote the VBA code which is adding the a new column to the right of the last column.What I want to do that is to copy the formula of last column and the range should change with suitable column.
For example I am using that formula on the last column.

```
=$A$186+SUMPRODUCT($B$14:$B$160;C14:C160)+SUMIF($C14:C160;"<1")
```

And I need to change "C" parts of the code.

I tried This code but it didn´t work

```
lastcolumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    With ActiveSheet
    .Cells(125, lastcolumn + 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=$A$186+SUMPRODUCT(" + Range("B14:B160").Address + ";" + .Cells(1, lastcolumn + 1).EntireColumn.Address + ")+SUMIF(" + .Cells(1, lastcolumn + 1).Address + " ;<1)"
    End With
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you try recording a macro?

Comment: No,I haven´t tried yet but when I add new column i need to change formula for that column and i need to do this dynamically.

Comment: The formula is not going to get copied automatically :) Please try and record a macro and then amend that code to copy paste the formula into the new column. And if you are still stuck then please post the code that you tried and where are you stuck :)

Comment: Please update the code in your question. And also mention what did you expect and what did you actually get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula automatically adjusts to the new position in the sheet when it is copied. Therefore you should simply copy it, instead of re-writing.

```
 With ActiveSheet
  lastcolumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  .Cells(125, lastcolumn).Copy Destination:=.Cells(125, lastcolumn + 1)
 End With
```

Greetings

Axel

Comment: Thank you for the reply :) But It didn´t work or I could not manage to do that.It is not copying the formula of last cell in that column..Thanks for helping me.

Comment: It works as follows: It does all with the active sheet. It takes the column number of that column, which is most right in row 1 and not empty, in [lastcolumn]. Then it copies the cell in row 125 and column [lastcolumn] into the cell in row 125 and column [lastcolumn +1]. This is not what you want?

Comment: Yes yes it is but when i click the row 125 and column [lastcolumn +1] it does not show the formula of the cell..

Comment: Well then you have to do some debugging. What value is stored in lastcolumn? Is this the right value? If not, it comes from row 1, are there enough not empty cells from left to right? ...

Comment: I found the bug :) Thank you very much for helping me

Comment: Please share this bug with us, it may be helpful for others.